# Node.js server doesn't let make post requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, url-routing

I am super new to Node.js, trying to create a simple server that registers, login and allows you to get the list of users. I didn't set up the front end yet, working sending requests through postman or manually(as hardcode).
I am getting a weird error when trying to send post requests(login and register), on the other hand, get request works properly.

What I get when trying to send a request through postman(It worked first time, then Istarted getting this error):
`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: usersBD.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: null } at Function.create (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:57:12) at toError (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123:22) at C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:265:39 at handler (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:942:24) at C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:350:13 at handleOperationResult (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:558:5) at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:277:5) at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20) at processIncomingData (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12) at MessageStream._write (C:\dev\Angular assigments\node-server-ivan\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5) at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12) at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10) at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20) at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12) at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9) { driver: true, index: 0, code: 11000, keyPattern: { username: 1 }, keyValue: { username: null } }`

Also in a browser when I changing the URL from  `http://localhost:5000`to `http://localhost:5000/login` or `http://localhost:5000/reg` I am getting this error, it also weird because yesterday I was getting console.log and everything worked properly.
`reg:1 GET http://localhost:5000/reg 404 (Not Found)`.
When I do `http://localhost:5000/users` I am getting `res.json` and everything works.
I do understand that Mongo error caused because I have something wrong with my user model.
But as I understand it shouldn'tt cause an error when I just add a URL in the search bar.
My index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRouter = require('./authRouter')//yes
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://Ivan:aldaron1@cluster0.fivve.mongodb.net/usersBD?retryWrites=true&w=majority'//yes
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(authRouter);
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
            useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true
        })
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

start()
```

my router:

```
const Router = require('express')
const router = new Router()
//const controller = require('./authController')
const User = require('./models/User');
const Role = require('./models/Role');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const { config } = "./config"
router.post('/reg',
    [
        check('email', `Username can't be empty`).isEmail(), //isEmail()
        check('password', `Password supposed to be in range from 4 to 20`).isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 })
    ],
    async (req, res) => {// req-request from user,res- response to user
        try {
            const errors = validationResult(req)
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: `Registration wasn't finished, please try again`, errors: errors.array() })
            }
            const { email, password } = req.body//user requesting it from server
            const candidate = await User.findOne({ email })
            if (candidate) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "User with this email is already registered" })
            }
            const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hashSync(password, 9);
            const userRole = await Role.findOne({ value: "User" });
            const user = new User({ email, password: hashPassword });
            await user.save()
            console.log("REG")//
            return res.status(201).json({ message: "User was succesfully registered" })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'Registration error' })
        }
    }
)
router.post('/login',
    [
        check('email', `Please in put a coorect email`).normalizeEmail().isEmail(), //isEmail()
        check('password', `Password supposed to be in range from 4 to 20`).isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 })
    ]//for password maybe exists

    , async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const errors = validationResult(req)
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: `Log in unseccussfull, please try again`, errors: errors.array() })
            }
            const { email, password } = req.body;
            const user = await User.findOne({ email })
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: `Username ${email} wasn't found` })
            }
            const validPassword = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password) //-checking up user password
            if (!validPassword) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: `Password isn't correct, please try again` })
            }
            const token = jwt.sign(
                { userId: user.id },
                config.get('jwtSecret'),
                { expiresIn: '1h' }
            );//fixed _id mongo shows in that way, that unchangable

            console.log("LOG")
            return res.json({ token, userId: user.id })//res.json возвращает на клиент сообщение

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'Login error' })
        }

    })
router.get('/users', async (req, res) => {//endpoints - probably later add "auth/"
    try {
        //instead of making inpoint we are creating them manually (for now)
        //const userRole = new Role();
        //const adminRole = new Role({ value: 'Admin' })
        //await userRole.save();//saving them to database
        //await adminRole.save();
        res.json("user displaying works")
        console.log("USERS")
    } catch (e) { }
})  // add authController as a callback and not as a method from another object 26.07
//router.post('/login',)
//router.get('/users', controller.getUsers)




//read about difference beetween hash/hashSync, compare, compareSync
module.exports = router
```

My user model:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');


//Schema described how user will be stored in database
const User = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, index: true, required: true },//email
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    roles: [{ type: String, ref: 'Role' }],
    //links:[{type:Types.ObjectId}] -- also add Types for import from mongoose
});

module.exports = model('User', User)// name and Schema
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This : MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Means that there is already a username which is null , so i think that you tried to signup before but the value was not read by your app for certain reason. Try dropping your collection and signing up again. Or check the user collection if there is a user with a value of null and remove it.

Note : Please edit your question to make it a minimal reproducible one